# Rmdir/rd access is denied (Corrupted folder)

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, permissions

I have a corrupted folder, I don't really know how it got that way. When I use rmdir in cmd as administrator, I get this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>rd "\\.\\C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\downloading\730" /s /q
\\.\\C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\downloading\730\bin\locales - Access is denied.
```

With a lot more lines of access denied. I can't "get permissions" with ownership as it gives me the same error. I tried `rd` without the `\\.\\` part and it doesn't work either. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first to run
[chkdsk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk)
to see if it can find errors.
To correct the errors run `chkdsk /f /r`, but take good backups before doing that.

If all else fails, boot up a Linux live USB and try to remove it from there.